# No module named imutils.perspective after pip installing

Tags: python, macos, opencv, pip

I am trying to follow this tutorial which requires `imtools`. It looks like I have the package installed, but the Python compiler cannot find it. What's going on here?

Tutorial: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/03/bubble-sheet-multiple-choice-scanner-and-test-grader-using-omr-python-and-opencv/

```
~/py:. cat test_grader.py
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform~

~/py:. python test_grader.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_grader.py", line 1, in <module>
    from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
ImportError: No module named imutils.perspective

~/py:pip install imtools
Requirement already satisfied: imtools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from imtools)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from imtools)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from imtools)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from imtools)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib->imtools)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.0,!=2.0.4,>=1.5.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib->imtools)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib->imtools)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib->imtools)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil->matplotlib->imtools)
~/py:.
```

Comment: imtoolsis different from imutils11

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Seems like you just installed wrong package.
The tutorial says you need imutils but you installed imtools instead.
Try to install imutils:

```
pip install --upgrade imutils
```

Answer (score 11):

1) Install **imutils**

```
pip install imutils
```

2) If imutils is already installed, check the installation path.

```
Requirement already satisfied: imutils in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

3) When I ran python program, I ran into following error:

```
ImportError: No module named imutils.video
```

In my case, imutils was only installed under /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages path, once I copied this folder to **/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages**, it worked! Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo pip2 install imutils`

I have solved this issue in Raspberry Pi 3 B using
`sudo pip2 install imutils`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about python but I needed to run a python script which needed this imutils.perspective part.

Here how it worked for me.

I installed all latest versions of using pip3 :

- python-opencv (4.4.0)
- imutils (0.5.3)
- numpy (1.19.2)

Still I could not find any perspective after importing imutils and trying tab complete after "imutils."

[image]

I tried uninstalling and reinstaling all packages but still no luck.
But I somehow managed to do it trying different codes.

I installed scipy(1.5.3) using `sudo pip3 install scipy` first.
Then using `import imutils` and `from imutils import perspective`
I was able to use it.
No need to import scipy, just install it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are installing `imtools` which is completely different than `imutils`

Run

`pip install imutils`

or

`conda install -c conda-forge imutils`

if you are in a conda environment.

Answer (score 0):

I installed imutils with "pip install packageName --target pathOfDirectorty"  in to the python 3.5 folder and everything went right

Comment: You might want to describe why it worked, to help the person to understand the solution described in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

most probably it is getting installed in global and not in local.
Check if imutils is in this folder 
**C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages**

copy paste imutils and imutils-0.5.2.dist-info folder in your local
**C:\usersid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages**

NB:AppData folder is hidden

or 
 `pip install --user  imutils`

Answer (score 0):

In my default base conda environment (using Anaconda prompt), did `pip install --user imutils` and accessing the same by `import imutils` from inside `my_env` created by virtualenv.... works fine..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pycharm to do this, select the View tab>Tool Window>Python Packages now search up imutils in the search bar, select imutils when it pops up, and click install. Try running your program again, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should uninstall imutils. For that you should use below command.

```
sudo pip3 uninstall imutils
```

After that you need to install upgrade the imutils. For installing upgrade imutils you can use

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade imutils
```

If you are use python2 then use pip2 insted of pip3