# Is there any tool to extract all comic strips from comic page?

Tags: image-processing, crop

I have comic page images like
[Link to image](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/_Kb-KmsoiPCUazLsn5VFP3RxTLYY9iQenCuE1sIy48nwLnCR03VzA4T8z9a_xnvgGqQal67tQ8auwzvQtAmTgc8ziMBLUIHzAZsRAyh21ebqzM1VkKYtK2CTEIsmoKeBzGn4Zg=s0)

And I want to extract all bordered comic strips from it as an individual image.
I don't intend to do it manually. I need some automatic tool for it.

Comment: Please tag the programming language.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any tool but with this script you should be able to do it:

[Extracted image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrKgn.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

img = "comic.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(img)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# blur
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)

# threshold it
(T, threshInv) = cv2.threshold(blurred, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# find contours
cnts, cnts_hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshInv.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
clone = image.copy()
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)  # order contours by area
for i,c in enumerate(cnts):
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    extent = area / float(w * h)
    
    crWidth = w / float(image.shape[1]) # width ratio of contour to image width
    crHeight = h / float(image.shape[0]) # height ratio of contour to image height
    
    # check if it's noise or a comic strip, change if necessary
    if crWidth > 0.15 or crHeight > 0.15 or extent > 0.8:
        # rotated bounding box
        box = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
        box = np.int0(cv2.cv.BoxPoints(box) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(box)) # gives us a contour
        
        warped = imutils.perspective.four_point_transform(clone, box.reshape(4, 2))
        cv2.imwrite(f'./image_{i}.png', warped)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: It says AttributeError: module 'imutils' has no attribute 'perspective'

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821954/no-module-named-imutils-pespective-after-pip-installing

Comment: Code worked. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64513895/3820677 for perspective problem. 
It would be better if all strips get cropped in sequence like we read them.
From top left to bottom right.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/04/20/sorting-contours-using-python-and-opencv/